# Matrix Multiplication Using GSL

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication, blas, gsl

I have two GSL matrices, `AT` and `A`:

```
gsl_matrix *A;    /* coefficient matrix A     */
gsl_matrix *AT;   /* coefficient matrix A'    */

AT   = gsl_matrix_alloc(nc, nr); /* Data matrix */
A    = gsl_matrix_alloc(nr, nc); /* Data matrix */

/* Initialize A */
for(i = 0; i < nr; i++){
  gsl_matrix_set(A, i, 0, 1.0); 
}

for(i = 0; i < nr; i++){
  for(j = 1; j < nc; j++){
    gsl_matrix_set(A, i, j, 1.0 / (double)(i + j + 1)); 
  }
}

gsl_matrix_transpose_memcpy(AT, A);
```

I would like to multiply these matrices and store the result in the matrix `ATA`, but I am having trouble understanding the GSL BLAS documentation.

I have initialized the `ATA` matrix:

```
gsl_matrix *ATA;  /* coefficient matrix A'A   */
ATA  = gsl_matrix_alloc(nc, nc); /* Data matrix */
```

I see that I can use `gsl_blas_zgemm` to multiply complex matrices, but these matrices are not complex.  How would I go about this?

**UPDATE**

I have tried:

```
gsl_blas_dgemm(CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 1.0, A, AT, 0.0, ATA);
```

It's causing the following error:

> gsl: blas.c:1354: ERROR: invalid length
>   Default GSL error handler invoked.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was multiplying the matrices backwards.  The proper line is:

```
gsl_blas_dgemm(CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 1.0, AT, A, 0.0, ATA);
```